# Passing generics to a component wrapped in a HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, higher-order-functions

I have an implementation of the ApolloGraphQL Query component.

When using the Apollo client Query component, typings can be passed as such:

```
import * as ApolloTypes from './__generated__/GetSubreddit';

 <Query<ApolloTypes.GetSubreddit, ApolloTypes.GetSubredditVariables>
      query={GET_SUBREDDIT}
      variables={{ name: selectedSubreddit }}
    >
...
</Query>
```

I have my own component which implements the Apollo Query component. Amongst other things, it adds some headers to each query. I want to be able to pass it typings in the same way as the normal query component, which is easy to do without the `connect` higher order component from "react-redux". I can't figure out how to pass the generics through the HOC. Any advice?

```
const GraphqlQuery = <T, TVariables = OperationVariables>(props: PropsType) => {
  const { query, variables, children, user, ...rest } = props;
  if (!user) return null;

  return (
    <Query<T, TVariables>
      query={query}
      variables={variables}
      context={{
        headers: {
          "X-User-Id": user.id,
        },
      }}
      {...rest}
    >
    ...
    </Query>
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = ({ user }: { user: IUserState }) => ({
  user,
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(GraphqlQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 options that I can think of that you can do to achieve this:

1. [Cast the export](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539324/7165303):

In your case it might be a little extra tricky but something like this might work as long as the HOC doesn't require any props. If it does you'll have to change the type you're casting as.

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(GraphqlQuery) as typeof GraphqlQuery
```

2. factory

```
export const createGraphqlQuery = <T, TVariables = OperationVariables>() => {
  const GraphqlQuery = (props: PropsType) => {
    const { query, variables, children, user, ...rest } = props;
    if (!user) return null;

    return (
      <Query<T, TVariables>
        query={query}
        variables={variables}
        context={{
          headers: {
            "X-User-Id": user.id,
          },
        }}
        {...rest}
      >
      ...
      </Query>
    );
  };


  const mapStateToProps = ({ user }: { user: IUserState }) => ({
    user,
  });
  return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {}
  )(GraphqlQuery)
};
```

Usage:

```
const GraphqlQuery = createGraphqlQuery<{}, {}>();

<GraphqlQuery ... />
```

There are definitely tradeoffs to each.