# How to define a generic type when exporting a component with generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using `typescript` for react component implementation. I am facing a problem on defining a generic type. Below is the code:

```
interface Props<T> {
  classes: { [className in keyof typeof styles]: string };
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  value?: T;
  label: string;
  onChange: (e: T) => void;
}

export const OutlinedInputField = withStyles(styles)(
  <T extends string | number>({ classes, style, value, onChange, label }: Props<T>) => {
    const type = typeof value  === 'number' ? 'number' : 'text';
    return (
      <Grid className={classes.root} style={style}>
        <TextField
          value={value}
          type={type}
          variant="outlined"
          label={label}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value as T)}
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
);
```

The above component requires a generic type on its value property. And it uses this type to decide whether it is number or text `Textfield`. What I don't understand is how I can use this component?

If I use this component in below ways (the value property has type number), the parameter on `onChange` is either `number` or `string`. It doesn't restrict the type to number. How can I enforce to use type `number` on `OutlinedInputField` component?

```
<OutlinedInputField value={value} label="Item weight (kg)" onChange={(n: number) => setValue(n)}/>
```

I tried below code but got an error `Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.`.

```
<OutlinedInputField<number> value={value} label="Item weight (kg)" onChange={(n: number) => setValue(n)}/>
```

Comment: Thank you for this question, I am having the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options that I can think of that you can do to achieve this:

1. [Cast the export](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55539324/7165303):

```
export const OutlinedInputField = withStyles(styles)(
  ({ classes, style, value, onChange, label }: Props<string | number>) => {
    const type = typeof value === "number" ? "number" : "text";
    return (
      <Grid className={classes.root} style={style}>
        <TextField
          value={value}
          type={type}
          variant="outlined"
          label={label}
          onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value as T)}
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  }
) as <T extends number | string>(props: Props<T>) => any
```

Usage

```
<OutlinedInputField<number> value={value} label="Item weight (kg)" onChange={(n: number) => setValue(n)}/>
```

2. factory

```
export const createOutlinedInputField = <T extends number | string>() => {
  const OutlinedInputField: React.FC<Props<T>> = ({ classes, style, value, onChange, label }) => {
    const type = typeof value === "number" ? "number" : "text";
    return (
      <Grid className={classes.root} style={style}>
        <TextField
          value={value}
          type={type}
          variant="outlined"
          label={label}
          onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value as T)}
        />
      </Grid>
    );
  };

  return withStyles()(OutlinedInputField);
};
```

Usage:

```
const OutlinedInputField = createOutlinedInputField<number>();

<OutlinedInputField value={value} label="Item weight (kg)" onChange={(n: number) => setValue(n)}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried your option1. There is no compilation error but the problem is the parameter type comes to `onChange(e.target.value as T)` doesn't respect the generic type which is `number`. Instead it becomes `string`.

Comment: In the first option, why is the last part `=> any`? Can I get rid of `any` and use some real type?